# Are Deep Anomaly Detection Approaches able to tell me what kind of anomaly it is?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, anomaly-detection

I recently started to look into anomaly detection. The deep learning approaches are trained on "normal" classes to build a classifier that can detect outliers (anomalies). Are these approaches able to classify these anomalies and if so how can they do it, if they have never seen these before?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a clustering algorithm to group the anomalies into groups that share similar features. However you can't really call that classification if you don't have classes to assign.